# Sorting a list using unicodes acending order, no loops, no sort(), using recursion

Tags: python, sorting, recursion, unicode

I wrote down this code and it works but when I convert it to `.py` and try to run it with an input,
I will write down  that recursion has reached limit or something similar.

Note: I'm not using `sort()`, `min()`, and other functions, as part of my assignment.

```
def sortl(lst, i, b_ord):
    if len(lst) == i:
        return lst
    
    elif b_ord > ord(lst[i]):
        lst[i - 1] = lst[i]
        lst[i] = chr(b_ord)
        b_ord = ord(lst[0])
        i = 0
            
    else:
        b_ord = ord(lst[i])
    
    sortl(lst, (i + 1), b_ord)

lst = list(input())
n = ord('0')
i = 0

sortl(lst,i,n)
print("".join(lst))
```

Comment: You don't return the sort recursive call

Comment: Your recursive call to `sortl` uses the full list each time, so the length does not reduce at each call, which means you have infinite recursion.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use `chr` or `ord`. You can write a simple recursive `sort` using a `insert` helper. We will use [inductive reasoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) to write each function.

1. if the list is one element or less, return the list
2. (inductive) there is at least two elements. `insert` the head, `l[0]`, into the `sort`ed tail, `l[1:]`

```py
def sort(l):
  if len(l) < 2:
    return l                          # 1
  else:
    return insert(sort(l[1:]), l[0])  # 2
```

`insert` inserts a value into a sorted list -

1. if the list is empty, return a singleton list of `value`
2. (inductive) the list as at least one element. if the list head is less than value to insert, prepend the list head to the recursive sub-problem
3. (inductive) the list has at least one element and it is larger than the value, prepend the value to the list

```py
def insert(sorted, value):
  if not sorted:
    return [value]                                  # 1
  elif sorted[0] < value:
    return [sorted[0]] + insert(sorted[1:], value)  # 2
  else:
    return [value] + sorted                         # 3
```

```py
print(sort([5,3,6,1,4,7,2]))
print(sort("gebafcd"))
```

```py
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```

This is definitely not the best performing sort technique but one that is simple enough to begin to understand recursion